# Is this a correct proof of the solution to a recurrence relation/functional equation?

Tags: solution-verification, recurrence-relations

I have seen that one can solve functional equations/recurrence relations such as

$$
z(x) = e^{\frac{x}{8}}z\left(\frac{x}8\right)
$$

by iterating, for example, in this case

$$
\begin{align}
z(x)
&= e^{\frac{x}{8}} z \left(\frac{x}{8}\right) \\
&= e^{\frac{x}{8}} e^{\frac{x}{64}} z \left(\frac{x}{64}\right) \\
&= ... \\
&= e^{\frac{x}{8} + \frac{x}{64} + \frac{x}{8^3} + ...}
\end{align}
$$

Which then just forms a geometric series, giving that

$$
z(x) = e^\left(\frac{x}{1-8}\right)
$$

I have tried to apply this to slightly different equations in the following manner, but I am not sure if this approach is correct or if it constitutes a proof of the solution

$$
A(z) = A\left(\frac{z}{3}\right) + 1, A(1) = 1
$$

Because, iterating, I get

$$
\begin{align}
A(z)
&= A\left(\frac{z}{9}\right) + 1 \\
&= A\left(\frac{z}{27}\right) + 1 + 1 \\
&= A\left(\frac{z}{81}\right) + 1 + 1 + 1 \\
&= ... \\
&= A\left(\frac{z}{3^n}\right) + n
\end{align}
$$

Then, if for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$, it is the case $z = 3^k$ there must exist an $n$ such that $n = k$, which means that $\frac{3^k}{3^n} = 1$ and $A(z) = k + 1 = \log_3(z) + 1$.

Would this be a valid proof or am I missing something? How could I make it more rigorous?